# Interlinear text editor

Tags: java, text

Is there a way in Java to display interlinear text so you can make only the alternate (odd-numbered xor even-numbered) lines editable? And, if so, would it be possible for the user to dynamically select which of the two sets of lines is editable?

Could this be simulated with two separate panels one on top of the other where the upper one has a transparent background?

Comment: Your question is incredibly vague.  Are you asking if there is a Swing control that displays text in such a way that only certain lines can be designated as editable?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.  Except I only need to designate that either all the even-numbered or all the odd-numbered lines are editable. I have a source document and a processor which generates a word-for-word "translation" of the source. I want the user to be able to either update the source for whatever reason or to update the translation.

Answer (score 1):

jEdit provides an editor pane that allows for collapsing/expanding controls within the textual content.  See the screenshot at http://www.jedit.org/index.php?page=screenshot&image=22

Answer (score 0):

Such a control hardly exists, or at least hardly is publicly available.

You can imitate it with a number of one-line input fields, styling / removing their borders to taste.